# connection commit function Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I was reading up on the documentation and saw that you only have to commit in once in a transaction?

Does the following count as one transaction or does each function count as a transaction?

```
def main():
    conn=pyodbc.connect(sqlconnectionstring) # Assume this connects to the database
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    function1()
    function2()

    conn.commit()

def function1():
    # does inserting here

def function2():
    # does inserting here and calls function 3
    function3()

def function 3():
    # does more inserting here
main()
```

Is that conn.commit() enough to commit all insertions in all the functions or would I have to pass the "conn" variable as an argument and commit inside each function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes thats enough to commit all the transactions as the ones like insert and delete will all be performed inside the functions, until one fail then you will find the old row.

but that one commit will change the database status to the recent one